# Developing in iOS on a OSX or Windows (VM), React Native or Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, windows, macos, react-native

I need to change my old Macbook Air into something better, that can take a bit of more heavy developing and not just small projects. I wanted to move to a Macbook Pro just to stay on the Apple area, but a thought hit me this morning surprisingly: "What if I bought a Windows laptop"

With the same money I'd be getting a much more powerful based windows laptop, I'd be able to play with, and develop with it as well which are all my pros, but what about developing in iOS?

If I install a OSX VM and download xCode on it, would it be the same? Therefore which laptop would you recommend the best, in terms of hardware? (Since last time I wanted to install a OSX VM on my AMD pc, I remember I kept failing just because of the hardware..)

And would you start right away with learning SWIFT or React Native? (I'm coming from a C++ and Java/Js background)

Sorry about the whole question, but I would like to invest my money in the right direction without regretting any choice..

I'd like to hear as many opinions as I can, in any point of view since I dont have experience in this field

Thank you!

Comment: *"What if I bought a Windows laptop"* and tried to run MacOS on it? Then you'd be in violation of Apple's licensing, as MacOS can only be installed on Mac hardware. You also run the risk of endless issues (especially as the OS is updated) and the risk of the system never been "quite" right - as it's not meant to be virtualised - personally, I've never seen a virtualised MacOS system that was "stable", "reliable" or "functional" beyond basic file browsing - but that's me

Comment: Also, two things, "general hardware/software" questions and "opinion" based questions are off topic on SO - probably not the best place to post this type of question (and no, I don't think any of SE site would be suitable either)

Answer (score 0):

First, yes you could buy some beafy Windows computer thats perfect for your gaming and some of your programming needs, but I wouldn't suggest it.

Windows isn't perfect for your programming needs. But what should you do?

I ran into this question myself two years ago, I needed a computer for heavy programming and gaming abilities.

Limitations for gaming on Mac has vigorisly been disappearing over the past couple years. You can play *almost* everything you'd want to on a Mac, whats nice is there are [perfect ways around all gaming problems](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/geforce-now/).

Limitations for programming, on the other hand, there are few. I would go as far as to say that Mac is the perfect environment for programming. Yes, you can program for iOS and MacOS, and Yes you can program everything else that Windows can do too.

In my perspective, I bought myself a Macbook Pro, and I have been able to do everything I've wanted to with it. If I feel like I want to program something that isn't iOS or MacOS, I can do it. But most of the time I'm programming iOS. It's incredibly seamless (not perfect, but seriously good). I spend a lot of time with Swift, and every once in a while I see myself programming Android. I can even game on it, I don't even use 3rd party software to play my games on Steam as most of them are supported.

Your next question, about what you should do if you want to get into iOS, aside from getting a Mac, start with Swift. You will see why everyone likes it. Swift is beautiful, and you'll wish you had been writing in it since you started programming. Start with the basic tutorials, just to get a feel for syntax, then start expanding and learning the Libraries like Foundation, UIKit, SpriteKit or whatever Library sparks your interests and needs.

Comment: Which Macbook have you bought in order to game as well? The 15' or 13' inch?